# For each test case, display the minimum number of days necessary to complete the plan. ALGORITHM ideas?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, theory

I have to write code to solve this question.  but first, I have to come up with an algorithm for it.  I have no idea how to do it.  Here is the question and what I was thinking of doing:

> The Canadian Space Agency (CSA) is in a race with their
>   American and Russian counterparts (NASA and Roscosmos, resp.) to land the rst man on the
>   Mars. They have broken down their plan into n tasks each taking exactly one day. Each task can
>   only be started when all its prerequisite tasks has nished. Clearly, there is no circular dependency
>   between the tasks. The CSA needs your help to determine the minimum number of days necessary
>   to complete the plan.

we are given a list containing the prerequisites for each task, so I know which task has which prerequisite.  for example. a list like `[[1,2,3],[],[],[]]` means that task 0 has prerequisites 1,2,3 and the other 3 tasks have no prerequisites.

what i was thinking of doing was checking every list and checking if it is 0-length. if it is, increase the day count by 1.  if it is not, iterate through the prerequisites and see if any of those can be done. if any of the prerequisites have prerequisites, i have to do those first.

I understand the theory, i just have no idea how to implement this.  I need to somehow keep track of the prerequisites I finished doing and then remove these prerequisites from any task that has it as a requirement.  I understand i could just make a list, but if the list input file is extremely large, it would take a long time, and my algorithm has to return an input iin under 1 second.

any help figuring out this algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do we know the number of teams, i.e. the number of tasks that can be done in parallel?
If there's only 1 team then the answer seem trivial: the number of days is the number of unique tasks, no matter in what order they are executed. 
On the other extreme, if the amount of teams is infinite then I think the answer is the max depth of the tree described by aruisdante and gassa below.

If there are cross-dependencies then I guess we could "simplify" the tree before computing its max depth, e.g. removing dependencies if they are already mentioned at an earlier step in another branch

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard tree/graph problem. Think about building a data structure that will have all the independent tasks as the leafs, and their nodes are the tasks that depend on them. You should then be able to come up with a search that will calculate the sum of days as it moves up levels on the tree.

Your node could look something like this:

```
class node(object):
      def __init__(children)
          self.children = children

      def days_to_complete()
          days = 1
          for child in children:
              days += child.days_to_complete()
          return days
```

Note that this class doesn't account for cross dependencies, but I'm not going to solve your homework for you ;)

Comment: like i stated in my question, i have a list of all the dependencies, i do not need to make a class for it.  all I have to do is come up with an algorithm and code it.  I do not want code. just help solving the algorithm.  I am trying to figure out how to keep track of the cross dependencies.  i even stated that in the question.

Also, i never asked for anyone to solve it for me. just give me some  hints.

Comment: You missed the point, that class is the algorithm that solves it as well. It's a tree problem. You're going to have to build a tree (at least to solve it in the most efficient way). I imagine that's the goal of the exercise. For example, see [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: Extending the node class to account for if it's already been expanded is pretty trivial and will solve the cross-dependency problem. At that point it's just figuring out how to construct the tree correctly from your input data.

Comment: I think that the correct way to find days is: "days = max ([1] + [child.days_to_complete + 1 for child in children])." That is, the number of days to complete a certain task is at the maximum of 1 and the greatest of that-number-plus-one for all the children.

Comment: i am very well aware that what was written in the code above returns a number of days required for the question. I did not get the asnwer i was looking for.  perhaps i was not clear enough in the question.  I know what to do for the basic case.  I need to know what to do when prerequisites  have requirements of their own, or if multiple actions have the same requirements.  I am not sure how to keep track of this and consider the requirement fulfilled in all the tasks that require it

Comment: And yes, it boils down to a classical graph problem of finding the longest path in a dag (directed acyclic graph). Here is some explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths.

Comment: You would only need `max` if you don't extend the class to account for if the node has already been expanded (in other words if it's already expanded, it doesn't take any time to complete *hint* *hint*).

Comment: The only thing this doesn't account for directly is 'orphaned tasks', that is if there are multiple tasks which is not depended on by any other task (there will always be at least one 'root' task). In which case you have multiple trees, and the result is the sum of them.